# Is there a mapping from an icosahedron to a sphere?

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I recently found a mapping from a cube to a sphere (see [Can someone please explain the cube to sphere mapping formula to me?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118760/can-someone-please-explain-the-cube-to-sphere-mapping-formula-to-me)), but is there also such a mapping from an icosahedron to a sphere? If so, is there also a way to map the sphere back to an icosahedron?

Comment: Yes there is a homeomorphism from the icosahedron to the sphere, which is given by taking any point on the sphere, considering the line through the point and the origin, and mapping to the intersection of that line with the icosahedron. Assume both are centered at the origin, of course. The inverse map is exactly the same, just replace the word icosahedron with sphere and vice versa.

Comment: This mapping basically implies that the sphere, the icosahedron, and projective space are all homeomorphic.

Comment: The ray that starts from the center of the icosahedron (assuming it is inscribed in the sphere) defines a bijection between both geometric objects. Any one icosahedron can be applied to the embedded icosahedron. So you can get a composite function that answers your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the explanatiin *there,* I suppose a simple radial scaling 
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\cr y\cr z\end{pmatrix}\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}x/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\cr y/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\\z/\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}\end{pmatrix}$$
would be good enough (esp. as the icosahedron is already close to a sphere.

For a map sphere $\to $ icosahedron, I would collect the unit normal vectors for the faces, then determine which of these has the largest scalar product with the given point on the sphere, then divide the point by that scalar product. (This maps to the circumscribed, not inscribed icosahedron, if that matters)

Comment: Isn't there still some distortion left, then? The cube to sphere mapping was made to minimize distortion. http://g2f.nl/0tzgwme.png here, points E, F, and G get projected onto the circle. On the triangle, |EF| = |FC|, but on the circle |EF| > |FC|, which is not what I want