# equidistant mapping from icosahedron to sphere

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

I am struggling to find an equidistant mapping that maps points from an icosahedron to a sphere, such that the points are spaced evenly (as much as possible) on the sphere.

A similar mapping from cube to sphere is described [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/118760/can-someone-please-explain-the-cube-to-sphere-mapping-formula-to-me), I'm looking for something similar to this. There is [an old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3634754/is-there-a-mapping-from-an-icosahedron-to-a-sphere) where someone asks a mapping from an icosahedron to a sphere, but there no attempt is made to spread the points evenly.

Comment: Could you say which vertices you take for your icosahedron ? Is it something like
$  (0,    \pm 1,   \pm  \phi),  (\pm \phi,  0,   \pm  1),  ( \pm  1,   \pm  \phi,  0) $ where $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio ?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what you mean by "the points are spaced evenly"?

Comment: @JeanMarie those are to my knowledge the easiest way to define an icosahedron but I'm open to any definition for the vertices if it makes a difference for the mapping

Comment: @JacobManaker if you take an icosahedron with points spread evenly on its faces, and 'blow it up' to be a sphere by normalizing every point, the points that started near icosahedron vertices will end up clumping together. The goal is to have a different mapping than just normalizing such that the points will have roughly the same distance from eachother on the sphere. Here is a visual representation of what that looks like when starting with a cube: https://youtu.be/sLqXFF8mlEU?t=1m37s